# setBrush() is not working perfectly on image

Tags: angular, html5-canvas, fabricjs

setBrush() is working fine on canvas but when I am trying to edit my image using setBrush() it's not working fine. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Please add some code with what you're trying to do and what doesn't work as expected.

Comment: this.canvas = new tui.ImageEditor("#draw_sign", { usageStatistics: false });
        this.canvas._graphics._canvas.freeDrawingCursor = 'url("pencile.png") -10 35, crosshair';
        this.canvas.startDrawingMode("FREE_DRAWING", { width: this.penPoint, color: this.penColor });  // i am doing like this pencile point work fine in google chrome  but not worked in safari